# How to display console in GUI for java

Tags: console

Is there a possible way to attach the console to a GUI so that the user will be able to enter commands into the console **from the GUI**?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the program is launched from the console, it can read and write from/to the console. There's nothing that makes a Java program "GUI" or "Console" except for the code.

If you want to always have a console regardless of how the program is launched, you could just code a frame to behave as one.

Comment: I made changes to my question. I want to enter the console command inside the GUI.

Comment: for example. the program prompts the user to enter in two values into the console. the program then prints out the two values added together and prompts the user if s/he wants to do it again. i want to do all of this within the gui.